# Gothic alphabet NOT fraktur

Tags: fonts

I have some actual Gothic (as in the alphabet used by the Visigoths and Ostrogoths) that I want to include in my .tex file (e.g., "").  Inserting the symbols in directly results in "ðŘŇÿðŘŇźðŘŇ£ðŘŇşðŘŇř" when I compile; however, given the OTHER use of 'gothic' (as a relative of fraktur) in LaTeX context, I'm having a heck of a time finding information on google.  Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which TeX distribution you use, which TeX engine (pdfTeX?, XeTeX? LuaTeX? something else?) and format (LaTeX? plainTeX? something else?) you employ, and -- for sure -- how the "real gothic" glyphs are encoded and stored. E.g., do they come in an OpenType file?

Comment: XeLaTeX should be able to handle that.

Comment: If you use xelatex or lualatex and the fontspec package you can just use the system font that ypu are using (on my browser your example shows in lucida sans unicode)

Comment: TeX Live includes the Junicode font, whose stylistic set 19 is for Gothic text.  You either type the Gothic characters directly into your source, or apply stylistic set 19 for automatic conversion of a transcription into Gothic letters.

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2014, @Thérèse.  How do I apply stylistic set 19?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is more a complement to David’s answer than a separate answer, but the question about my comment needs more space for clarification than a comment allows.

Here’s a small example, extracted and simplified from the Junicode manual:

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[
  Contextuals=Alternate,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=7}]
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
\begin{document}
ss19 produces Gothic letters automatically from transliterated text,
while ss20 produces Latin letters from Gothic. Example:
{\addfontfeatures{StylisticSet=19}jabai auk ƕas gasaiƕiþ þuk þana
  habandan kunþi in galiuge stada anakumbjandan, niu miþwissei is
  siukis wisandins timrjada du galiugagudam gasaliþ matjan?}

You can also enter Gothic text directly, without using a stylistic
set. Example: 

Since the Gothic alphabet has no distinction between upper- and
lower-case, capitals and lower-case letters are transliterated the
same way.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code]

Depending on when you last updated your TeX Live, you may need to use the older `fontspec` syntax:

```
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Alternate,Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=7}]{Junicode}
```

If you don’t want to use Junicode throughout your document, you can do something like this:

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily\goth{Junicode}[
  Contextuals=Alternate,
  StylisticSet=19,
  Scale=MatchLowercase]
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
\begin{document}
Plain English, in TeX Gyre Pagella, followed by {\goth jabai auk ƕas
  gasaiƕiþ þuk þana habandan kunþi in galiuge stada anakumbjandan, niu
  miþwissei is siukis wisandins timrjada du galiugagudam gasaliþ
  matjan}, supplied by Junicode.
\end{document}
```

Comment: After talking with Will Robertson at the TUG meeting, I'm more and more convinced that the old syntax is better.

Comment: @egreg I prefer the old syntax too.  Fortunately, it’s still supported, so the OP can use it if she likes.

Comment: @egreg Slightly off-topic, but I've grown to appreciate the new syntax. When you have 20 lines of OpenType features specified as `setmainfont` options, I like to see immediately what the main font is, instead of having to scroll down 20 lines to find it.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\begin{document}

I have some actual Gothic (as in the alphabet used by the Visigoths
and Ostrogoths) that I want to include in my .tex file (e.g.,
"").

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the Gothic alphabet is in Unicode (in the Unicode block called `Gothic`, 27 letters, from U+10330 to U+1034A).

Sample of some system fonts, under `fontspec`:

[image: font samples]

As mentioned, input can be direct, or with a Gothic keyboard, or with macros (of the `\symbol{"10330}` sort), or with a mapped font:

[image: latin to gothic map]

With xelatex:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\sampletext{      }

%U+10330 to U+1034A

\newcommand\ffaname{Analecta}
\newcommand\ffbname{FreeSerif}
\newcommand\ffcname{Junicode}
\newcommand\ffdname{LeedsUni}
\newcommand\ffename{MPH 2B Damase}
\newcommand\fffname{Noto Sans Gothic}
\newcommand\ffgname{Quivira}
\newcommand\ffhname{RomanCyrillic Std}
\newcommand\ffiname{Segoe UI Historic}
\newcommand\ffjname{Skeirs}

\newfontface\ffa{\ffaname}
\newfontface\ffb{\ffbname}
\newfontface\ffc{\ffcname}
\newfontface\ffd{\ffdname}
\newfontface\ffe{\ffename}
\newfontface\fff{\fffname}
\newfontface\ffg{\ffgname}
\newfontface\ffh{\ffhname}
\newfontface\ffi{\ffiname}
\newfontface\ffj{\ffjname}

\newfontface\ffatr{\ffaname}[Mapping=latin-to-gothic,Scale=2,Colour=blue]



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\ffaname & \ffa \sampletext \\
\ffbname & \ffb \sampletext \\
\ffcname & \ffc \sampletext \\
\ffdname & \ffd \sampletext \\
\ffename & \ffe \sampletext \\
\fffname & \fff \sampletext \\
\ffgname & \ffg \sampletext \\
\ffhname & \ffh \sampletext \\
\ffiname & \ffi \sampletext \\
\ffjname & \ffj \sampletext \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{24pt}

Input can be direct ({\ffa }), or with macros (of the  \textbackslash symbol\{\verb|"|10330\} 
$\to$  
{\ffa
\symbol{"10330}}
 sort), or with a mapped font:

\noindent a~{\ffatr a} 
b~{\ffatr b} 
g~{\ffatr g} 
d~{\ffatr d} 
e~{\ffatr e} 
q~{\ffatr q} 
z~{\ffatr z} 
h~{\ffatr h} 
th~{\ffatr th} 
i~{\ffatr i} 
k~{\ffatr k} 
l~{\ffatr l} 
m~{\ffatr m} 
n~{\ffatr n} 
j~{\ffatr j} 
u~{\ffatr u} 
p~{\ffatr p} 
ch~{\ffatr ch} 
r~{\ffatr r} 
s~{\ffatr s} 
t~{\ffatr t} 
w~{\ffatr w} 
f~{\ffatr f} 
x~{\ffatr x} 
hw~{\ffatr hw} 
o~{\ffatr o} 
|~{\ffatr |} 

\vspace{24pt}

\ffatr 
wulfilas gutiska 

atta unsar thu in himinam

\end{document}
```

Mapping `.map` file (compile into `.tec` file with `teckit_compile`):

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "latin-to-gothic" ;
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

 U+000061 <>  U+010330;  a
 U+000062 <>  U+010331;  b
 U+000067 <>  U+010332;  g
 U+000064 <>  U+010333;  d
 U+000065 <>  U+010334;  e
 U+000071 <>  U+010335;  q
 U+00007A <>  U+010336;  z
 U+000068 <>  U+010337;  h
 U+000074 U+000068 <>  U+010338;  th
 U+000069 <>  U+010339;  i
 U+00006B <>  U+01033A;  k
 U+00006C <>  U+01033B;  l
 U+00006D <>  U+01033C;  m
 U+00006E <>  U+01033D;  n
 U+00006A <>  U+01033E;  j
 U+000075 <>  U+01033F;  u
 U+000070 <>  U+010340;  p
 U+000063 U+000068 <>  U+010341;  ch
 U+000072 <>  U+010342;  r
 U+000073 <>  U+010343;  s
 U+000074 <>  U+010344;  t
 U+000077 <>  U+010345;  w
 U+000066 <>  U+010346;  f
 U+000078 <>  U+010347;  x
 U+000068 U+000077 <>  U+010348;  hw
 U+00006F <>  U+010349;  o
 U+00007C <>  U+01034A;  |
```

so that typing `atta unsar thu in himinam` in the mapped font produces:

[image: gothic text]